# Shell Method Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

[image]

Use the shell method to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the regions bounded by the curves and lines about the​ y-axis.

$y=x^2$, $y = 5 -4x$, $x = 0$ for $x \ge0$

I have the integral set up as

$$2\pi \int_{-5}^0(x)(-4x+5-x^2) \, dx$$

I'm having issues typing that in correctly. The integral evaluates to $875\pi/5$ when the answer is $11\pi/6$. Why is my setup wrong? Everything I look at about it seems right and am having trouble.

Comment: It seems like you're doing the corresponding region with $x \leq 0$ rather than $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region that is being rotated can be seen below; it's the region below $y=5-4x$ and above $y=x^2$, with $x\in[0,1]$. So, the volume is$$\int_0^12\pi x(5-4x-x^2)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{11\pi}6.$$

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be a factor of $2 \pi$ rather than just $\pi$?

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor Sure. My bad. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I misread the the last bit in the sentence as "$x = 0$ for $x \ge 0$" instead of "$x=0$ COMMA for  $x \ge 0$"